# Is there a way to synchronise iframe scrolling with div scrolling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js, webflow

I have a Three.JS background that is embedded to an HTML page as an iframe and will be placed in Webflow. It is a scrollable background with custom made objects and animation. Another div is placed on top of it which contains the content of the page. With their heights the same, the idea here is to synchronise the scroll of these two HTML elements. How does one accomplish this?

Comment: There is no way to control the behavior inside an iFrame from code outside the iFrame.

Comment: Well, that's a bummer... any suggestion for an alternative approach?